# iOS - Reset the command center / remote player

Tags: ios, audio, video, uiwebview, avplayer

I'm using different kinds of players in my app. I have some kind of control over all of them, but one of them I don't, at all.

When I play an embedded video from a UIWebView, specifically.

My issue is, the app requires audio to be played in background, which works fine. Note, the video's audio does not need to be played in background. But that means I need to use the remote controls (command center & lock screen commands).

My issue is the following :

After I've played a video from an embed, the remote controls still control that video, even though it's been dismissed. And when I press "play", it plays both my radio AND the embedded video.

How can I "clear the memory" of the command center ?

I have enough information to know when to apply a solution, I don't know what the solution is though.

Solution can include a complete disability to use the command center while playing the embed video, or until my radio is played. Solution can include some kind of "hard reset" of the command center.

Actually, any solution is welcome.

Answer (score 1):

This question is a little bit old, but I just fixed this issue and feel like this could help someone out. The thing that was preventing me from reseting the command center was that I had added target actions that were persisting past the instance of my view controller's lifecycle.

Here's what my code looked like.

On the view controller:

```
var commandPlay: Any?
var commandPause: Any?
```

When adding the targets:

```
commandPlay = commandCenter.playCommand.addTarget {event in
        self.startButtonTapped(self.startButton)
        MPNowPlayingInfoCenter.default().nowPlayingInfo?[MPNowPlayingInfoPropertyPlaybackRate] = 1.0
        return .success
    }

commandPause = commandCenter.pauseCommand.addTarget {event in
        self.startButtonTapped(self.startButton)
        MPNowPlayingInfoCenter.default().nowPlayingInfo?[MPNowPlayingInfoPropertyPlaybackRate] = 0.0
        return .success
    }
```

At dismiss to remove the targets (important part):

```
commandCenter.playCommand.removeTarget(commandPlay)
commandCenter.pauseCommand.removeTarget(commandPause)
```

Comment: Thanks for posting this. This worked for me. The trick was to declare the variables you mentioned above as @State variables in Swift 5. I had to modify my play / pause code to add the commandPlay / commandPause functions. Don't forget to define commandCenter in your atDisappear() function. I've made some edits to your code. Well done.

Comment: Never mind - it says the suggested edit queue is full so I can't edit your question. Don't forget this line: let commandCenter = MPRemoteCommandCenter.shared();. You'll also want to stop receiving remote events: UIApplication.shared.endReceivingRemoteControlEvents().